# Unable to display Toast message when phone is PIN locked

Tags: android, android-toast, android-security

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(
                Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
                        | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                "ToastActivity");
        wl.acquire();
        Log.w("TOAST","show");
        Toast.makeText(this, "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

In the above code I have made my **Activity to Launch when the screen is security locked(pin/swipe) too**.

However the Toast message is **not displayed while its launched when the phone is security locked**.

When I unlock the device and launch again, the **toast message is seen**.

***Initially I tried without the WAKE_LOCK changes, it did not work. Then I tried with WAKE_LOCK changes too, still it did not work.***

How to fix this issue. **Is this an Android limitation?**.

Answer (score 1):

Toasts cannot be displayed on the lock screen.

Lock screen widgets have also [gone extinct](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen) from Android version 5.0 onwards.

Best idea is to use a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up), like so:

```
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                    .setContentTitle("Alert message here")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert) //required, otherwise throws 'no valid small icon)'
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC); //viewable on lock-screen

            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify("test", 0, builder.build());
```

You can also include buttons that trigger intents.